# sql server authentication user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

very basic question. sql server 2008, created new login and gave it sql authentication mode. checked status is enabled. Tried to connect to same server instance, login failed. What is going wrong? thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Did you give that new login any access to any of the databases??

Just the login alone is not worth much and it's only half the story. That user can log in to SQL Server - big deal. You will also need to create users in database based on that login! Or check some boxes in the Login's "User Mappings" page to give it access to specific databases.